# how to install Ubuntu desktop/server on Android phone (flash)

Tags: system-installation, android

I've got a few old Android phones (MI and Huawei), I had their bootloader unlocked and I am thinking about repurpose them.
To make them useable, i would like to install Ubuntu desktop (preferred) or Ubuntu server.
I am willing to spare some time on the project.

1. can i use the iso to install?
2. what modifications to make to the Ubuntu code?
3. how to find drivers?

Comment: I heard Ubuntu Touch has been deprecated @muru

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Ubuntu Touch](https://ubuntu-touch.io/), which has an active community very much about a derivative of Ubuntu on Phones.

(Stock) Ubuntu cannot be installed on phones for a variety of reasons (Ubuntu Touch explains those reasons). AskUbuntu currently limits itself to official releases and flavors, and so does not currently answer Ubuntu Touch questions.